# How to fix error Element type is invalid expected a string?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an expo application that shows me 3 tabs and when I go to the 'Camera'
tab I always get an error. I tried almost all solutions but this doesnt wan't to work.

The error is : "Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid expected a string (for build-in components) or a class/function (for composite elements) but got undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of "CameraExample"

Here is the tree :

!https://nsa40.casimages.com/img/2019/01/24/190124124747913567.png

here is my file index.js :

```
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';
import SignUpForm from './SignUpForm';
import CameraExample from './CameraExample';

const routeConfigs = {
Login: {
    screen: LoginForm,
},
SignUp: {
   screen: SignUpForm,
},
Camera: {
   screen: CameraExample,
},
};

const tabBarOptions = {
tabBarOptions: {
activeTintColor: '#88cc88',
inactiveTintColor: '#aaaaaa',
showIcon: true,
scrollEnabled: false,
indicatorStyle: {
  display: 'none',
  },
   style: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
   },
 },
 tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
};

export default TabNavigator(routeConfigs, tabBarOptions);
```

CameraExample/Component.js

```
import { Camera, Permissions } from 'expo';
import React, { Text, View, Component } from 'react';

class CameraExample extends Component {
   state = {
    hasCameraPermission: null,
    type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
};

async componentDidMount() {
  const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
  this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted' });
}

render() {
  const { hasCameraPermission, type } = this.state;
  if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  } if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={type}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            flexDirection: 'row',
          }}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              flex: 0.1,
              alignSelf: 'flex-end',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({
                type: type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                  ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                  : Camera.Constants.Type.back,
              });
            }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{ fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 10, color: 'white' }}
            >
              {' '}
             Flip
              {' '}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
       </Camera>
      </View>
    );
   }
 }

module.exports = CameraExample;
```

and CameraExample/index.js

```
export { default } from './Component';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it needs to be written this way

CameraExample/index.js

```
import Component from './Component'
export default Component
```

OR

```
module.exports = require('./Component')
```